# android camera error - error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32

Tags: android, android-camera

Does anyone have an idea what would cause the below error?

queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32

I'm using SurfaceTexture and android.hardware.Camera in my app. The above error occurs when I try to start/stop preview and open/close camera too many times.

Below are the error logs:

```
10-27 15:39:54.173 I/ActivityManager( 2329): Process com.google.process.gapps (pid 20050) (adj 1) has died.
10-27 15:39:54.213 E/SELinux (23446): [DEBUG] seapp_context_lookup: seinfoCategory = default
10-27 15:39:54.213 D/dalvikvm(23446): Process 23446 nice name: com.google.process.gapps
10-27 15:39:54.213 D/dalvikvm(23446): Extra Options: not specified
10-27 15:39:54.213 I/ActivityManager( 2329): Process com.google.android.gms (pid 23282) (adj 1) has died.
10-27 15:39:54.243 D/SecCameraCoreManager( 1888): disableMsgType: 0xffff
10-27 15:39:54.243 D/Camera_HAL( 1888): atom_disable_msg_type msg_type=0x0000ffff
10-27 15:39:54.243 D/SecCameraCoreManager( 1888): stopPreview
10-27 15:39:54.243 D/SecCameraCoreManager( 1888): virtual void android::SecCameraCoreManager::stopPreview():stop IT Policy checking thread
10-27 15:39:54.243 D/ShotSingle( 1888): stopPreview
10-27 15:39:54.243 D/Camera_HAL( 1888): atom_disable_msg_type msg_type=0x000003c2
10-27 15:39:54.243 V/ShotSingle( 1888): stopPreview(1)
10-27 15:39:54.243 D/Camera_HAL( 1888): atom_stop_preview
10-27 15:39:54.243 E/Surface ( 1888): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
10-27 15:39:54.243 E/Camera_PreviewThread( 1888): Surface::queueBuffer returned error -32
```

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/kitkat-release/include/utils/Errors.h says -32 is `DEAD_OBJECT` (`-EPIPE`).  Not sure what would be causing that.

Answer (score 3):

This happens if your SurfaceTexture gets garbage collected while you're trying to feed it camera data.

Make sure you're holding on to a reference to the SurfaceTexture in your app, not just passing it to the camera instance and letting it go out of scope.

When shutting down, make sure you've stopped preview before destroying the SurfaceTexture (usually this means not leaving the app's onPause until preview is stopped and the camera is closed), and on startup, make sure your SurfaceTexture is valid before starting preview.